# Displaying Google Calendar Events and Custom Events in fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

Im using the amazing FullCalendar JQuery plugin and need to display a Google Calendar Events aswell as my own custom events. Code Below.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Now Im aware that I cannot have two `events` attributes, but i need the data from both sources displayed. How can i go about this?

Thanks in advance, 
Grant

Comment: Can you get the data from the url with an ajax call and then add your own event data to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for Reading, but I've found the solution. All I had to do was Add an event source after initializing my Calendar. Code below.

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
>     var date = new Date();
>     var d = date.getDate();
>     var m = date.getMonth();
>     var y = date.getFullYear();
>
>     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>         theme: true,
>         header: {
>             left: 'prev,next today',
>             center: 'title',
>             right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
>         },
>         editable: true,
>         events: [
>             {
>                 title: 'All Day Event',
>                 start: new Date(y, m, 1)
>             },
>             {
>                 title: 'Long Event',
>                 start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
>                 end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
>             },
>             {
>                 id: 999,
>                 title: 'Repeating Event',
>                 start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
>                 allDay: false
>             },
>             {
>                 id: 999,
>                 title: 'Repeating Event',
>                 start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
>                 allDay: false
>             }
>         ]
>     });
>
>     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic');
> });
> ```